# Would Spark preserve key order with this sortByKey/map/collect sequence?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

Let us say, we have this.

```
val sx = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 39), (4, 47), (3, 51), (1, 98), (2, 61)))
```

And we later call this.

```
val sy = sx.sortByKey(true)
```

Which would make

```
sy = RDD[(0, 39), (1, 98), (2, 61), (3, 51), (4, 47)]
```

And then we do

```
collected = sy.map(x => (x._2 / 10, x._2)).collect
```

Would we always get the following. I mean, would the original key order be preserved, despite changing the key values?

```
collected = [(3, 39), (9, 98), (6, 61), (5, 51), (4, 47)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Applying the `map()` transformation and calling `collect()` does *not* change the ordering of the array elements returned by `collect()`. To prove this, we simply have to show that:

- map will not modify the ordering of elements in an RDD
- collect will always return elements of an RDD in the same array ordering on every call

The first point is pretty easy to prove. Under the hood, a call to `map()` just produces a `MapPartitionsRDD` by iterating through every partition and calling the function argument passed to `map()` on every element within a partition. Therefore, no ordering is modified here as the the element ordering within each partition stays the same.

The second point can be proven with a closer look at `collect()`. The following code is the implementation for `collect()` as well as the function that collect calls.

From `RDD.scala`:

```
def collect(): Array[T] = withScope {
  val results = sc.runJob(this, (iter: Iterator[T]) => iter.toArray)
  Array.concat(results: _*)
}
```

From `SparkContext.scala`:

```
def runJob[T, U: ClassTag](rdd: RDD[T], func: Iterator[T] => U): Array[U] = {
  runJob(rdd, func, 0 until rdd.partitions.length)
}
```

The `runJob()` function being called (which is an overloaded method) passes a `Seq[Int]` containing the order in which partitions will be processed to another `runJob()` method. This order is eventually bubbled up to the scheduler, which will determine how the action will process partitions. So with the case of `collect()`, we will always process partitions in a sequential order starting with the first one.

Therefore, since neither `map()` nor `collect()` modifies the partition order or the ordering of elements within a partition, you will see the same ordering for the result of your collect every time. However, if you apply a transformation that requires a shuffle before your collect, all bets are off as the data will be repartitioned.

Comment: Which transformations require shuffles before collect?

Comment: @MetallicPriest [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations) should show you a good baseline on which transformations trigger shuffles. Specifically, "operations which can cause a shuffle include repartition operations like `repartition` and `coalesce`, ‘ByKey operations (except for counting) like `groupByKey` and `reduceByKey`, and join operations like `cogroup` and `join`".