# Scala: copying a dataframe column into array and preserving the original order

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` with one timestamp column and one integer column such that no timestamp appears in more than 1 record. It looks like this:

```
timestamp  | value
------------------
2019-07-03 | 2100
2019-04-15 | 1828
2019-06-01 | 948
2019-07-12 | 2912
[etc.]
```

Using the following I can order this by timestamp:

```scala
df.createorReplaceView("tmp")
var sql_cmd = """select 
                    * 
                 from 
                    tmp
                 order by
                    timestamp asc""";
var new_df = spark.sql(sql_command);
```

and get `new_df` looking this way:

```
timestamp  | value
------------------
2019-04-15 | 1828
2019-06-01 | 948
2019-07-03 | 2100
2019-07-12 | 2912
[etc.]
```

Is there a way to put the contents of `value` of `new_df` into an array `new_df_array` such that the ordering of the numbers of that column is preserved? (That is: `new_df_array[0] == 1828`, `new_df_array[1] == 948` etc.)

Comment: AFAIK, a simple `collect()` won't alter the ordering of the records in your dataframe.

Comment: @sachav Thanks for your comment - that would be fantastic! Can you point me to  documentation that can ensure me that `collect()` does not affect the ordering in the dataframe?

Comment: While a collect would certainly maintain order within partitions, I am unsure if the order of the partitions themselves would be preserved.

Comment: While I could not find any reference in the documentation, here is an interesting answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289249/would-spark-preserve-key-order-with-this-sortbykey-map-collect-sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
val array = new_df.coalesce(1).sortWithinPartitions($"timestamp").collect()
```

Note that is no dataframe, but a plain scala array